# ElasticSearch: search in two different ranges with different aggregations for each

Tags: elasticsearch

This is an odd question, but I'm trying to avoid calling ES twice to obtain different data from two different range of times.
Let's say that:

from "2016-10-01 to 2016-10-31" I want to SUM the field "orders.total_sales" (just an example) and another sum "reviews.count".

And from "2016-09-01 to 2016-09-30"
I only want to sum "orders.total_sales".

(The truth is I need like 50 sum aggregations on the first range), but for the second range, I only need 2).

I know it's possible to filter by two ranges of anything using should instead of must. But is it possible to distinguish the result from each range in order to operate with them (aggregations sum).

I don't think it's possible, but just in case someone has come with this issue before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) for this purpose. You would basically write two filters for two different range and then do sub aggregations as you want.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "range_one": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "your_date_field": {
            "gte": "2016-01-01",
            "lte": "2016-02-02"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_orders": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "your_sum_field1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "range_two": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "your_date_field": {
            "gte": "2016-02-01",
            "lte": "2016-03-02"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_orders": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "your_sum_field2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! based in what you pasted, I ended up with something like this (next post)

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing something like this with (due to ES errors, until I got it working)

Thank you very much! It worked, but not with filter, but the idea is the same
I did something like this:

```
{
  "timeout" : 1500,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "term" : {
            "businessId" : "101598"
          }
        }  ,
        {
          "range" : {
            "date" : {
              "from" : "2016-10-15T03:00:00.000Z",
              "to" : "2016-10-31T03:00:00.000Z",
              "include_lower" : true,
              "include_upper" : true
            }
          }
        }]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "range_one": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "date",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2016-10-15T03:00:00.000Z",
            "to": "2016-10-22T03:00:00.000Z" 
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_orders_sales": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "orders.totalSales"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "range_two": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "date",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2016-10-23T03:00:00.000Z",
            "to": "2016-10-31T03:00:00.000Z" 
          }                    
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_orders_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "orders.orderCount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case performance and speed is important and since my two ranges are consecutive, I thought I could filter by the business_id (I need) and from the oldest date (start date of the first range) to the newest date (end date of the second range), assuming that aggregation works with the result of the query (otherwise, it will search all documents, and it would be great just to have it doing the aggregation operations over a resultset obtained just one). But I'm new with ES, so not sure I'm seeing it right. However, it's working like charm!
Thanks a lot1

Comment: You have done it right, It is faster to aggregate on less results.